# Is it possible to set the @Qualifier annotation to a private static variable in a Java class?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm currently using JDBC Templates to fetch data from a database. For this, I've created a "static" Repository class (i.e. a class marked "final" and with a single private constructor). In it, I'm trying to set the values of two private static `PlatformTransactionManager` class variables.

However, my IntelliJ tells me that the value of the class variables are always null and I have no idea how to solve this issue.

I was hoping on just using them as local variables in the static constructor, since what I really want are the JdbcTemplate constants that I'll prepare using the PTMs. Since, I don't know how to do that, I tried making them into `private static final` fields. But IntelliJ didn't allow that either.

To try to solve this, I have looked at these threads:

- [Passing variables to @Qualifier annotation in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589479/passing-variables-to-qualifier-annotation-in-spring)
- [How to make spring inject value into a static field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324372/how-to-make-spring-inject-value-into-a-static-field)

. . . as well as this note on Qualifiers:

- [The Java EE 6 Tutorial: Using Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html)

*Important Notes:*

- The project I'm working on does not have XML configuration files. There are [*]Config files in the project that handle the configurations.
- One more thing to note is that I don't quite understand annotations in general (be they in Java, C#, etc.). That is, I know the basic idea behind them, but I have no idea how they really work . . . and I don't remember much of the Spring framework anymore (since I've been working on Core Java and C#.NET for quite some time now). So . . . I'd appreciate any help to solve this issue.

The following is a sample of what my source code looks like:

```java
private final class Repository {

  private Repository() {}

  private static final JdbcTemplate TEMPLATE1;
  private static final JdbcTemplate TEMPLATE2;

  @Qualifier( "transactionManager1" )
  private static PlatformTransactionManager manager1;

  @Qualifier( "transactionManager2" )
  private static PlatformTransactionManager manager2;

  static {
    // NOTE: For this one, IntelliJ shows me an error stating, "Value 'manager1'
    // is always 'null'."
    DataSource source =
      ( ( JpaTransactionManager ) manager1 ).getDataSource();

    TEMPLATE1 = new JdbcTemplate( source );

    // NOTE: Here, there is no error ... at least, IntelliJ isn't showing any.
    source = ( ( JpaTransactionManager ) manager2 ).getDataSource();

    TEMPLATE2 = new JdbcTemplate( source );
  }

  public Map<String, Object> fetchData() {
    return TEMPLATE1.queryForList( "..." ); // TODO: something
  }

}
```

Comment: You have to use `@Autowired` to inject `PlatformTransactionManager` ,but it does not work on the static fields . So do your requirement is that you must use static field for the `PlatformTransactionManager`? If not , I suggest you to consider changing it to use non-static field for the dependencies which normally are regards as a much better practise than using static field ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `ApplicationContextAware` interface to get context object and using this context object you can get the bean even in static context.

```
public class ApplicationBeansProvider implments ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
    }
}
```

and then in your code you can do something like

```
private final class Repository {

  private Repository() {}

  private static final JdbcTemplate TEMPLATE;

  private static PlatformTransactionManager manager = ApplicationBeansProvider.getBean("transactionManager");


  static {
    DataSource source =
      ( ( JpaTransactionManager ) manager ).getDataSource();

    TEMPLATE = new JdbcTemplate( source );

  }

  public Map<String, Object> fetchData() {
    return TEMPLATE1.queryForList( "..." ); // TODO: something
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh! This is the solution I ended up going with. :)