# What is the best way to select bean implementation from application.yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application in which I want to Autowire a bean for which implementation is specified in application.yaml. What is the best way to achieve it?

```
@Component
public class FooFormatter implements Formatter {}

@Component
public class BarFormatter implements Formatter {}

public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("value_from_config")// The implementation is specified in application.yaml file
    private Formatter formatter;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing variables to @Qualifier annotation in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589479/passing-variables-to-qualifier-annotation-in-spring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve it is to use [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html).

So given the followings :

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "app.formatter", name = "impl", havingValue = "foo",matchIfMissing = true)  
public class FooFormatter implements Formatter {

}

@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "app.formatter", name = "impl", havingValue = "bar")    
public class BarFormatter implements Formatter {

}
```

Then to enable `FooFormatter` only , configure the application properties as :

```
app.formatter.impl=foo
```

To enable `BarFormatter` only , configure the application properties as :

```
app.formatter.impl=bar
```

If no `app.formatter.impl` is defined in application properties , it will default to `FooFormatter` (because of the `matchIfMissing = true`)